# Configuring a Jinja template in Cisco DNAC Template editor

Tags: jinja2

I am configuring a Jinja template in Cisco DNAC Template editor to provision new switches. The problem I am having is getting Jinja to split the string variable within the Cisco Template tool. I tried using this split command.

```
{% set list1 = variable1.split(';') %}
```

This works fine if I hard code in the {{ HOSTNAME }} variable, for example using ABC-DEF-111-AS-10-11-12-13

```
{# {% set hname = '{{ HOSTNAME }}' %} #}
{% set hname = 'ABC-DEF-111-AS-10-11-12-13' %}
Device name is {{ hname }}

{% set list1 = hname.split('-') %}
{% for list in list1 %}
<p>{{ list }}</p>
{% endfor %}

The campus is {{ list1[0] }} 
The building is {{ list1[1] }}
Room number is {{ list1[2] }}
Switch type is {{ list1[3] }}
IP address is {{ list1[4] }}.{{ list1[5] }}.{{ list1[6] }}.{{ list1[7] }}
```

However, when I use the {{ HOSTNAME }} variable to input the hostname, the split command will not split the hostname, instead it passes the hostname through in its entirity within {{ list1[0] }}. This happens even if I use the variable directly within the split command, for example.

```
{% set list1 = '{{ HOSTNAME }}'.split('-') %}
```

I have also tried splitting the resultant {{ list1[0] }} but it too just passes the hostname on through in its entirety.

I am not sure if this is a problem with the version of Jinja used in the Template Editor because I get a systax error when ever I tried using this split command:

```
{% set item1, item2 = variable1.split(';') %}
```

Is there away to get {{ HOSTNAME }} split? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is that I should change the variable into a statement like this:

```
{% set list1 = **HOSTNAME**.split('-') %}
```

Comment: Hi Ali, thank you for your reply, I tried your suggestion using ** but this produced the Error: unexpected '**".

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting a similar thing using the Template System Variables built into DNAC.
In my case I was trying to break out major.minor.patch in the softwareVersion.
I found that I could not use any of the built in variables directly in a split routine.

My workaround was to create a new variable that "adds" a null string "" to the built variable.
I was then able to split the temp variable.

```
! device.softwareVersion  >>>>>>       {{ __device.softwareVersion }}
{% set sw_ver = __device.softwareVersion + "" %}
! sw_ver = {{sw_ver}}

{% set sw_ver_split_list = sw_ver.split('\\.') %}
! SW major release is {{ sw_ver_split_list[0] }}
! SW minor release is {{ sw_ver_split_list[1] }}
! SW patch level is {{ sw_ver_split_list[2] }}
```

Yields this:

```
! device.softwareVersion  >>>>>>       17.6.4
! sw_ver = 17.6.4

! SW major release is 17
! SW minor release is 6
! SW patch level is 4
```

One last note. The split values are still in string format.  So if you want to do mathematical operations (i.e. <, > ,+) you have to filter them as an integer.

```
{% set major = sw_ver_split_list[0]|int %}
{% set minor = sw_ver_split_list[1]|int %}
{% set patch = sw_ver_split_list[2]|int %}

{% set major_ver_threshold = 17 %}
{% if major < major_ver_threshold %}
! The major release of {{ major }} is less than {{ major_ver_threshold }}.
{% else %}
! The major release of {{ major }} is NOT less than {{ major_ver_threshold }}.
{% endif %}
```

Which adds this to the results:

```
! The major release of 17 is NOT less than 17.
```